# SQL Merge two rows with same ID but different column values (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to merge different rows into one when they have the same id but different column values.

For example :

```
    (table1)

    id       colour

    1        red
    1        blue
    2        green
    2        red
```

I would like this to be combine so that the result is :

```
    id     colour1    colour2

    1      red        blue
    2      green      red
```

Or

```
    id     colour

    1      red, blue
    2      green, red
```

Or any other variation of the above so that the rows are joined together some way.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHY do you want to do this? Is it strictly and exclusively for reporting purposes, or do you want to use the result for storing the data and/or further processing? If it is exclusively for reporting: It can be done in SQL, but it is better done in your reporting application, whatever you use. If it is for storing and/or further processing, this is a TERRIBLE idea. The data is currently in "first normal form". You are looking to do something that violates first normal form - you are going towards a very badly flawed data model.

Comment: I edited your post to delete the `merge` tag; `merge` is something completely different and unrelated to your problem, it has to do with updating, inserting and deleting to/from a target table using data in a source table.

Comment: I have simplified the table so that I would be able to get a simpler answer, in reality both columns together are the primary key and also foreign keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read my Comment first - you shouldn't even think about doing this unless it is ONLY for reporting purposes, and you want to see how this can be done in plain SQL (as opposed to the correct solution, which is to use your reporting tool for this job).

The second format is easiest, especially if you don't care about the order in which the colors appear:

```
select   id, listagg(colour, ', ') within group (order by null)
from     table1
group by id
```

`order by null` means order randomly. If you want to order by something else, use that in `order by` with `listagg()`. For example, to order the colors alphabetically, you could say `within group (order by colour)`.

For the first format, you need to have an a priori limit on the number of columns, and how you do it depends on the version of Oracle you are using (which you should always include in every question you post here and on other discussion boards). The concept is called "pivoting"; since version 11, Oracle has an explicit PIVOT operator that you can use.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Yes, it is simply to see how it is done in SQL.

Comment: Hi, it worked! Can you explain how to remove duplicate values from the row? For example my value in one record contains `red, red, red, blue, blue, blue, blue`, whereas I need `red, blue`.

Answer (score 3):

The following would solve your problem in the first of the two ways that you proposed. `Listagg` is what you would use to solve it the second of the two ways (as pointed out in the other answer):

```
select    id,
          min(decode(rn,1,colour,null)) as colour1,
          min(decode(rn,2,colour,null)) as colour2,
          min(decode(rn,3,colour,null)) as colour3
from (
      select id,
             colour,
             row_number() over(partition by id order by colour) as rn 
      from   table1
     )
group by  id;
```

In this approach, you need to add additional case statements up to the maximum number of possible colors for a given ID (this solution is not dynamic).

Additionally, this is putting the colors into color1, color2, etc. based on the alphabetical order of the color names. If you prefer a random order, or some other order, you need to change the `order by`.

Comment: This will work if it is guaranteed that there are always at most three colours for each id (and this assumption would be best stated explicitly in the Answer). I would also add a comment about the "order by colour" (similar to the comment in the "other answer").

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

Here `student` is the name of the table and `studentId` is a column. We can merge all subjects to the particular student using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT studentId, GROUP_CONCAT(subjects) FROM student
```

Comment: For SQL Server: `STRING_AGG (subjects, ',')` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT`.

However, for this answer to be corrected it should be: 

`SELECT studentId, GROUP_CONCAT(subjects) FROM student GROUP BY Id`