# SQL Merge two rows with same ID but different column values in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to merge different rows into one when they have the same id but different column values in Microsoft sql. I found a discussion about the same need but in oracle see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831690/sql-merge-two-rows-with-same-id-but-different-column-values-oracle)

i created the table in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76881/1/0)

for example, i have

```
UserId  WorkGroup

Bill    PC-money
Bill    PC-windows
Linus   PC-free
Linus   PC-open
```

I would like to see

```
UserId  WorkGroup1 WorkGroup2
Bill    PC-money   PC-windows
Linus   PC-free    PC-open
```

my access to microsoft sql is read-only

thanks for you ideas

Comment: The key word is `PIVOT`. There have been a lot of questions how to pivot a table in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT USERID, 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(WORKGROUP), ',', 1), ',', -1) AS WORKGROUP1,
 if(length(GROUP_CONCAT(WORKGROUP)) - length(replace(GROUP_CONCAT(WORKGROUP), ',', ''))>=1,  
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(WORKGROUP), ',', 2), ',', -1) ,
       NULL)WORKGROUP2 
FROM MyTable1
GROUP BY USERID;
```

You can check here [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2626c/1).

Considering every `USERID` have two entries,you can try above query.

Comment: Hi, i get this error 'GROUP_CONTACT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Are you trying into mysql??

Comment: i m really sorry not in mysql but Microsoft SQL!! i will correct the discussion.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeDescamps It's okey..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select UserID,
Substring((Select ',' + WorkGroup  From MyTable B Where B.UserID=A.UserID For XML Path('')),2,8000) As Workgroups
From MyTable A where workgroup like '%%PC-%%'
Group By UserID
```

Comment: http://forums.sqlteam.com/t/merge-two-rows-with-same-value-but-different-column-values-in-microsoft-sql/11033/2?u=lp.descamps